# How does the Flash have powers on Arrow S04E19?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse, the-flash, continuity, arrow

Flash didn't have powers on The Flash S02E19, but has powers at the end of Arrow S04E19 just one day later. How is that possible?

The answer is probably a plot hole or to not completely  trust episodes order between those shows (although it was accurate since Barry appeared on Arrow in the 2nd season). Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's not enough in-universe clues to sync the shows up, but most likely the answer is that *Flash* and *Arrow* are out of sync. There's a slim chance a future *Flash* episode will refer to this event, and we'll know for sure, but probably not.

This isn't unusual, and in fact, the exact same thing happened last season. At some point, *Flash* ended up out-of-sync with *Arrow*, and Felicity and Ray appeared as a couple on *Flash*, trying to figure out the ATOM suit, at a point where that made no sense on *Arrow*. Similarly, it's very difficult to fit the two season finale crossovers (specifically, Oliver being in Central City, in League armor) into their respective timelines, and no hint was given how that was possible.

The most reasonable explanation is that *Arrow* is lagging behind *Flash*, and this funeral and related events took place before Barry lost his speed.

Comment: Maybe they are not lagging but are far ahead.

Answer (score 0):

A Few episodes back the Arrow showed Oliver and Barry standing by the grave with caption that said 6 months later that might mean something

Comment: Yes, it means Arrow s04e01 was six months before s04e19. That doesn't explain if Flash is also exactly the same schedule.